# ASP.Net button not resetting to default

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, dialog

I am using "BLOCKUI" jquery confirmation dialog box plugin, Its working perfectly except its not reseting the button it gets poped up on,

Maybe its a logical mistake :/, here's the code,

**Script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/1033/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="JS.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { 

        $("input[id$='btDelete']").click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '620px' } });
        }); 

        $("input[id$='yes']").click(function() { 
            $.blockUI({ message: "" }); 
        }); 

        $("input[id$='no']").click(function() { 
            $.unblockUI(); 
            return false; 
        }); 
    }); 
</script>
```

**Div Tag**

```
<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="cphSubmit" runat="server">
<div id="question" style="display:none; background-color:Menu; cursor: default">
    <div align="center">
        <br /><asp:Label ID="Label1"  runat="server" Text="Deleting this eDecision will remove all site content and uploaded documents.<br />Are you sure you wish to continue?" CssClass="headertext"></asp:Label><br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
        <asp:Button ID="yes" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click" Runat="server" Text="Yes"></asp:Button>
        <asp:Button ID="no" Width="200px" Height="25px" CssClass="gradientbutton" Runat="server" Text="No"></asp:Button><br /><br /><br />
    </div>
</div>
```

**Button**

```
    <td>
    <asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click"
    OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" Text="Delete" Width="200px"  />
</td>
```

[Here;s the Plugin Link](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#dialog)

If I make changes to the button as

```
<asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" CssClass="gradientbutton" Text="Delete" Width="200px"  />
```

The dialog box appears and then disappears :S

and IF button is like below, dialog appears but then even if i press "No" delete button stays disabled,

```
<asp:Button ID="btDelete" runat="server" CssClass="gradientbutton" OnClick="btDelete_Click"
    OnClientClick="this.disabled=true;" Text="Delete" Width="200px"  />
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
    $("input[id$='btDelete']").click(function() {  
        $.blockUI({ message: $('#question'), css: { width: '620px' } }); 
        return false;
    });
```

And your button without the OnClientClick. You already have a client-click event above. The return false will stop the event bubbling and prevent the submit of the asp.net button.

Comment: `return false` doesn't prevent bubbling. It prevents the default action.

Comment: Really? I thought return false did both. (preventDefault and stopPropagation). Thanks for the info.

Comment: Turns out that jQuery handles `return false` differently than plain JS. So, we were both right?